# Missing some functions in my Qt class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm starting using Qt for a GUI, but I have some problems with headers/libraries because I'm missing some functions.

Two of them are:

```
<obj_name>.setModal(true);
<obj_name>.exec();
```

They should work fine as in [the video I'm following](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUH_gu2HdQE&feature=relmfu) (at 6:30).

Because I did exactly what they did, so my clue is his version isn't the same as mine.

I want to know which header should I include.

Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNew_Window_triggered()
{
    MyDialog mDialog;
    mDialog.setModal(true);
    mDialog.exec();

}
```

Even with:

```
#include <QDialog>
```

Still doesn't work. It says:

> C:\QtSDK\teste-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MinGW*_Qt_SDK__Debug..\teste\mainwindow.cpp:22: error: 'class MyDialog' has no member named 'setModal'.

`mydialog.h` code:

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MyDialog;
}

class MyDialog : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyDialog();

private:
    Ui::MyDialog *ui;
};

#endif // MYDIALOG_H
```

It is included in `mainwindow.cpp` and `mydialog.cpp` (the header is just the class).

Comment: Please tell us which version of Qt and which OS you are using. How do you think we can help you without this information? Are we magicians? -- Apart from that, `QDialog` has those two methods in 4.x as well as 5.0. So your object probably doesn't inherit from `QDialog`. Did you just create a simple *widget* instead of *dialog*?

Comment: Im using the lastest version! For windows

Comment: Did you include "mydialog.h"? And show us "mydialog.h", it is probably the most important piece of code here. And **please** don't just write "it doesn't work". Tell us **what happens**, i.e. paste the compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyDialog` is no `QDialog`. You created it as a "main window" which is no dialog.

To hot-fix this (without recreating the dialog using QtCreator), just rewrite the inheritance in `mydialog.h` 
from:

```
class MyDialog : public QMainWindow
```

to:

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
```

In your `mydialog.cpp` you find the implementation of the constructor of `MyDialog` which calls the superclass constructor. Since we just changed the superclass, we also have to change this call from:

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
...
```

to

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
...
```

<del>You also have to fix your .ui file to morph the whole widget from a main window to a dialog. I'll add how to do so in a few minutes (have to find it out)</del> You don't need to touch the .ui file.

Comment: Ok, let me study inheritance to do this.Just a sec '

Comment: Didnt work: Error>> C:\QtSDK\teste-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\teste\mydialog.cpp:5: error: type 'QMainWindow' is not a direct base of 'MyDialog' Error>>>>>>C:\QtSDK\teste-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\teste\mydialog.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to 'Ui::MyDialog::setupUi(MyDialog* const)'

Comment: @DhiegoMagalhães Sorry, I forgot to mention that you also have to change one line in the .cpp file, see my edit. The "is not a direct base of" error typically means that a wrong constructor is called within your constructor. For the second error, try to fully recompile the whole project plus re-run qmake. I'm not sure if we have to make changes to the .ui file after all.

Comment: **Please** describe *what* didn't work. What do you think should "didn't work" help me to help you? Give me error messages, more code, ...

Comment: Did you fix both the header file and the cpp file to use QDialog instead of QMainWindow? Please post the exact error you got.

Comment: Ok, i will say what was happening:
In Qt, when you write the name of a function, it automatically shows the possible functions. For eg, when you're writing "setcen..." automatically shows "setCenterWidget". I was writing "setMod..." and modal wasnt appearing. Today, it worked, I REALLY DONT KNOW WHY, maybe because i haven't restarted the computer after installing Qt. Anyways, tnks for helping! No problems any more

Comment: The command completion most likely did not reprocess the file after the change to make the base class QDialog. I do not use QtCreator much so I am not sure what is needed to trigger reprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call setModal() from MyDialog class, but it inherits from QMainWindow, which has no setModal method. You must inherit from QDialog instead.

Comment: That's one of the downsides of using the designer.

Comment: do mean what leemes meant? didnt work

Comment: @wingleader *What* is a downside of the designer?

Comment: @leemes i'd say you have less control over the code, but that's __**just my opinion**__

Comment: @wingleader Yeah, in general I agree that the designer reduces flexibility, but your answer is about from what basic widget type (dialog, main window or pure widget) you inherit. The designer doesn't even know that you inherit from widget or from dialog, so this is done on C++ side only! (A bit different is the main window, for which the designer introduces a menu and status bar for example.) For more details see my answer. Or just compare the .ui file if you choose "QWidget" vs. "QDialog" in the assistant when you create the .ui file. They should look (almost) the same.